# Using cell values with variables returning run-time error 91

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to copy cell values into variables, but I'm getting this error "Run-time error 91", can someone clarify this for me.

My code:

```
Sub XPTO()
'
' XPTO Macro
'
Dim var1 As Range
Dim var2 As Integer
Dim var3 As Integer
Dim var4 As Integer

Range("C4").Activate
While Not ActiveCell = ""
    var1= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Select
    var2= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
    var3= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Select
    var4= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
Wend

End Sub
```

My main objective is to save the values of those cells in order to copy them to another worksheet in a different layout. In the other worksheet I will find var1 and copy var2,var3,var4 into place with the new layout.

Comment: If variable is dimmed as range, then you use `set`. `dim var1 as range: set var1 = activecell.offset(0,0)` ... then to check if your var1 give an expected cell/range, `var1.select`. So, in this case, I think you should dim your var1 to var4 as range. Then use set var1= .... , set var2 = ... til set var3 = .... Later if you want to check if those variable give you correct cell/range, you add a "check code" something like `var1.select: var2.select` and so on.

Comment: Here is the Microsoft Learn page on that specific error; it might be helpful. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/object-variable-not-set-error-91

Answer (score 1):

I was referring to a range and then trying to get a value, which only works with a string. This is the working code.

```vb
Sub XPTO()
    '
    ' XPTO Macro
    '
    Dim var1 As String
    Dim var2 As Integer
    Dim var3 As Integer
    Dim var4 As Integer
    
    Range("C4").Activate
    While Not ActiveCell = ""
        var1= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 0).Value
        var2= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Value
        var3= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 3).Value
        var4= ActiveCell.Offset(0, 4).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
    Wend
    
End Sub
```